# mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication on web hotsting

Tags: php, mysql

I read a lot of answer about this problem, but my real problem is that I cant understand the real solving:

I follow the instruction to change password, set it with 24 characters, but nothing change!
I try:

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0; 
SET GLOBAL old_passwords = 0;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('xxxxxx');
```

but nothing change!
My web hosting dont permit change my.cnf!

Any solution?

Comment: Where do you entering commands it? Please give us more information about problem.

Comment: I make change on phpMyadmin.... but now, when access to phpMyAdmin I give Error Sanitize 2!!!! (I think the password is too long!).
I try the script on same mysql db, but from another server.... and work fine!
So the problem is the php version?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload privileges because the server caches them.  Just type "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" in a query window on phpmyadmin.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html

Comment: ok...but when i try to log to phpMyadmin i receive Error sanitize 2!
Is it possible to make a call by script ex. $sql = "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"?

Comment: doing FLUSH PRIVILEGES give this error in phpMyadmin: #1227 - Access denied; you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation 

Before I make select user(), current_user();

Comment: Does the Error sanitize 2 give a line number?  Is it coming from php or javascript?

Comment: Also since you didn't specify a user in your SET PASSWORD statement, I would assume it is changing the password for the user you are logged in as (in this case the user that connects phpMyAdmin).  On servers I've worked on in the past, there is a directory on the server that has a config file (config.inc.php) with the password to connect to the database in it.  You may need to change the password in that php file for phpMyAdmin to be able to connect.

Comment: I cant FLUSH privileges in my phpMyadmin, becouse I'm not root user, and my provider dont permit.
My question is: my script works fine on same mysql db, but in different server. So the problem is the new version of php in the new server. Is there a way to solve  mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I solve so by launching a script with this sql:

```
SQL = "select user(), current_user()"
SQL = "SET Password = PASSWORD('password')"
SQL = "SET SESSION old_passwords = 0"
SQL = "SET Password = PASSWORD('old_password')"
```

WIthout Flush (for me is impossible with this hosting!).